# Entity Framework not executing Get on every property

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1.  A simple table with no foreign keys is mapped to an object (TransmissionHistory table and object.)  Yet when I save, one of the fields is NULL, although the value has clearly been set and I can see it when walking through the code and writing to a log.  (Field name is WhoDidIt.)

On further investigation, I replaced the auto properties in the object with Get and Set and private backing property.  It turns out, when the database Save is executed, the other properties' "Get" is executed, but not my problem WhoDidIt property.

Here is part of the class definition:

```
    public partial class TransmissionHistory
{
    private string _id;
    private string _transmissonTable;
    private string _whoDidIt;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value;  }
    }
    public string TransmissionTable
    {
        get { return _transmissonTable; }
        set { _transmissonTable = value;  }
    }

    public string WhoDidIt
    {
        get { return _whoDidIt; }
        set { _whoDidIt = value;  }
    }
```

Here is the code that creates and saves the object.

```
        TransmissionHistory trxHist =  new TransmissionHistory();
        trxHist.Id = guid.ToString();
        trxHist.TransmissionTable = "MyTransmission";
        trxHist.WhoDidIt = "Me";
        _db.TransmissionHistories.Add(trxHist);
        _db.SaveChanges();
```

When I put breakpoints in, it's clear that the database SaveChanges is hitting the Get method for the other two properties, but not WhoDidIt.  So even though the trxHist object has a value in WhoDidIt, it is always saved to the database as NULL.  This was built as "Database First" and Visual Studio built the object.  I've also tried dropping and rebuilding the table and regenerating the code, and changed the field name.  What is happening here?

Comment: Silly question: does the table in the database have a matching column?  Sorry, had to ask.

Comment: Yes, it does.  I did "database first", so the table was created first and I generated the class from the table.  The field is currently varchar 12 and nullable (SQL Server 2008).  Originally, it was not nullable, and my inserts were failing because of this field.

Comment: So you're using EDMX file?  Check the mappings in the EDMX, make the conceptual model's field is mapped to the storage model's field

Comment: Yes, all that looks good.

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away on it's own, but here's what I think caused it:

We're using a Database First approach.  The underlying table in the database had changed, but the EDMX model was not refreshed.  Even though this particular field had not changed, it seemed to give this odd behavior until we refreshed our model from the database.